# Filter by first element from Java List

Tags: java

I would like to filter by first element in the list and get average after group by second element.

```
public class MyClass{
int index;
String fruit;
int quantity;
public MyClass(int index, String fruit, int quantity){
    this.index = index;
    this.fruit = fruit;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getIndex(){
    return index;
}

public String getFruit(){
    return fruit;
}

public int getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

ArrayList<MyClass> test = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

MyClass t1 = new MyClass(1, "apple", 6);
test.add(t1);
MyClass t2 = new MyClass(2, "apple", 6);
test.add(t2);
MyClass t3 = new MyClass(1, "banana", 6);
test.add(t3);
MyClass t4 = new MyClass(2, "banana", 6);
test.add(t4);
...
Myclass t20 = new MyClass(10, "apple", 6);

if (MyClass.getIndex() <= 5){
    Map<String, Integer> map = test.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(MyClass::fruit, averagingLong(MyClass::quantity)));
}

//desired return 
// {apple: 12, banana:12}
}
```

I am filtering the first element which is index before I get average using Java Stream. Is this proper way to do this?

Comment: There are no methods `fruit` and `quantity` in `MyClass` to be used as method references, use existing getters (or rename them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said averaging but your question showed the following:

> //desired return
> // {apple: 12, banana:12}

To provide the desired return you need to do `summingInt`, not `averagingInt`

```
Map<String, Integer> map = test.stream().filter(t->t.getIndex()<=5)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::getFruit,
                Collectors.summingInt(MyClass::getQuantity)));
                
System.out.println(map);
```

Prints

```
{banana=12, apple=12}
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter by index, you can add filter predicate after stream condition like below

```
Map<String, Double> map = test.stream().filter(m -> m.getIndex() <= 5)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::getFruit, Collectors.averagingInt(MyClass::getQuantity)));
```

And also you may need to wrap code from ArrayList test inside a method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW do you know why I do get this? "The method averagingInt(MyClass::getQuantity) is undefined for the type MyClass"

Comment: @BryanK. possibly you're missing static import for `Collectors.averagingInt`